# What is the difference between these empty array String.Split method calls?

Tags: c#, string, refactoring, split

Any difference between these two lines of code?

1) `someString.Split(new[] { ';' });`

2) `someString.Split(';');`

I see the first one in the code I'm working on and was wondering if I could safely change it to number two or why they chose to do it the first way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public string[] Split(params char[] separator)
```

The method argument is `params char[]`. The `params` keyword means you can provide an array explicitly, or let the compiler create one for you. In your first form, you are providing the array explicitly. You will need to use this form, of course, if you want to use other [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx) of the method to specify additional behaviors. Otherwise, you can simply use your second form and list the separators in line and comma-delimited for ease of use.

Why the previous coder(s) chose the first form over the second, I cannot say. I am not aware of a method form in a previous framework version that required the explicit array. However, you should be safe to change forms if you so choose, and you will assuredly test to verify the expected behavior.

Comment: +1 for placing emphasis on fact, that both lines use one and the same Split overload.

Answer (score 2):

In the **first option**, if you want to **split on multiple characters** then you can specify that in your character array. If there is going to be only a single character for split then use the 2nd option.

Consider the following example:

```
string someString = "Somestring;abc.def.abc"; 
//following will return 4 elements array, after splitting on ';' and '.'
string[] splitedArray = someString.Split(new[] { ';','.' }); 
//following will return 2 elements in array after splitting on a single character
string[] splitedOnSingleCharacter  = someString.Split(';');
```